# Standard buffer size of an apache ftp client(downloader)

Tags: java, apache, ftp, sftp

How much is the standard buffer size of an apache ftp client(ftp downloader)?

```
    int BufferSize;
    ftp = new FTPClient();
    ftp.setBufferSize(BufferSize);
    ftp.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));
    int reply;
    ftp.connect(host);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to [`FTPClient`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html), you can call [`getBufferSize()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#getBufferSize%28%29) to determine this yourself, at runtime. There are other similar functions for specific (send, receieve) buffers.

<sub>For what it's worth, I don't use Java, and I've never even heard of FTPClient. I simply Googled for "apache ftp client", clicked the first link, and Ctrl+F searched for "buffer". Learning to answer questions yourself will greatly help you in the long run.</sub>

Comment: This application is used for downloading a file from an ftp server,so what is the standard buffer size needed?

Comment: Are you having any problems with the default? If not, then don't worry about it. I'm sure the author picked some reasonable default.

Comment: default it is zero,to improve need to set a buffer size

Comment: @user872297 What makes you think changing the buffer size will improve your download speeds? (It might or might not.) The easiest way would be to just try it and see.